# Proper values for gluPerspective() or glFrustum()

Tags: opengl

I've been using `gluPerspective` and somewhat have a grasp on what it's doing and how it works. But I still don't quite understand how to use it for any effect beyond that of where it starts and stops. changing the `zfar` and `znear` never seems to affect anything much. Am I missing a cool effect? what are some ranges of values and what visual distortions can you do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't miss any cool effects. `zNear` and `zFar` (or `nearVal` and `farVal`) are the distances to the near and far clipping planes. They define the way the camera space z-coordinates map into the projective-space depth values. The z-buffer can store values between -1 and +1. Points `zNear` far from the camera will map to -1 and points `zFar` from the camera will map to +1. Anything outside that range will be clipped.

Note that both these functions as well as everything I've said is legacy. You are better to learn modern OpenGL pipeline, with OpenGL 4+. There you are responsible for doing the exact math explicitly, which I think will improve on your understanding of how this works. Also today you actually can [use floating point z-buffers](https://stannum.io/blog/0UZsbE) with disabled depth clipping making all the near/far clipping planes obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

The geometric meaning of the projection matrix in the OpenGL function `GLFrustum()`, which was explained in the  official guide of OpenGL (the nineth edition of the book, OpenGL programming guide-- the official guide to learning OpenGL), from an algebraic point of view, actually corresponds to many geometric meanings that are unluckily different from what the authors expected.

A significant difference between them are:
1. in the official guide, the authors are illustrating a compound linear transform with one of its factors as `central projection`, so the final compound perspective projecction matrix should be a singular or degenerated matrix;
2. while still in the official guide, at the appendix, the `GLFrustum()` perspective projection matrix is a nonsingular 4 times 4 square matrix!

Note that: The authors are trying to explain a nonsingular matrix into a theoretically singular one!

The following matrix decomposition (not unique) corresponds to one of the geometric meanings of the nonsingualr `GLFrustum()` matrix:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUVlA.png)

All of the above matrix factors except for No. (2), have their geoemtric meaning clearly redefined in [Unified Framework of Elementary Geometric Transformations](https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.0998). If you choose this factorization as the geometric meaning explanation of the `GLFrustum()` perspective projection matrix, you will have to make sure any computation or transforms you are doing in your code are consistent to its geometric meaning.

So when you are programming with OpenGL `GLFrustum()`, probably may have to compare with what has been illustrated in the official guide and what the `GLFrustum()` perspective projection matrix really means from the view point of pure algebraic projective geometry, and use any one of your own.